# iOS View Controller Containment Parent/Child calls dance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make a container view controller that works similarly to navigation controller. When I add something to the stack what do I do with the view controller that is a already there?

It is still my child but I don't want it's view in the view hierarchy. Should I call removeFromParentViewController on it, and just keep a separate stack with it, in that stack? So when the view above is popped off, I can check what view I should push back in order to go back to previous one.

Or should I just remove its view, without removeFromParentViewController call, and add another child controller, and its view to container view hierarchy?

Basically what do I do with the controllers that aren't on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The "stack" is just an array that a navigation controller uses to keep track of its view controllers. If you're building your own, you will need to have an array also. The way a navigation controller works, when a controller is pushed, that controller is added to the array, and if one is popped, that one is removed from the array. When you do a transition, the one that's going off screen should call removeFromParentViewController, so it's no longer in the hierarchy (but if it's going away because of another one being pushed, you would leave it in your array -- that's how the controller knows which one to go back to on a pop). You should use transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: to do your transitions from one controller to the next.